# "Live notifications" feaure

Tags: php, ajax, server

I want to add "live notifications" feature for my users: When they receive a new message(via the chat system) then display a notification badge on the chat icon in the navbar.

I was thinking to do: AJAX calls with setInterval:(As seen on another post here)

The AJAX call:

```
setInterval('checkUpdates', 2000);
function checkUpdates() {
   $.get('/check_updates.php?timestamp=' . lastTime, function (results){
    // do stuff here
    }
);
```

The PHP code:

```
$timestamp = $_REQUEST['timestamp'];
$results = query('SELECT message FROM messages WHERE messageTime > "$timestamp"');
echo fetch($results);
```

I have a few questions before:

1) Since I want the update-checking to be constantly running, and the navbar is always present (always on the top of the page), is the navbar.php file the correct place to put that AJAX call?

2) How badly does that affect performance of the website, to have AJAX calls constantly running every 2 seconds?

3) Is there a better way? Do websites like Facebook have an efficient way to immediately popup the chat window whenever you get a new message, or it's thanks to their huge amount of servers?

Thanks

Comment: Investigate *web sockets* or *server side events*. Repeated AJAX calls scale terribly and are only good for DDoSing your own server at any sort of moderate scale.

Comment: My current chat is based on repeated ajax calls with setInterval, you suggest me to redesign it and completely change it to web sockets? Any link to begin with? Any tutorial on how to create a web-sockets chat system?

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggest, though it is going to be quite a change, and is too broad to really get into here. Especially with PHP as a backend it'll be a bit of an uphill battle, and you probably won't be able to use most standard shared hosting providers to host a web socket based PHP site. So, uhm, yeah… if you want to do it properly, prepare for doing some learning.

Comment: you can use NodeJS : https://github.com/ethaizone/Example-chatroom-with-NodeJS-PHP/blob/master/pages/chat.php

Comment: Since you're using PHP, http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world is a chat system example on Ratchet.

Comment: Do they support saving the messages into a database? Because it's a chat system like on WhatsApp where you need to save these messages

Comment: Sure, you can do anything you want in your server-side code.

Comment: Both Ratchet (via standard PHP database APIs) and NodeJS support saving to databases.

Comment: Alright, so out of the examples you suggested, which one should be better for: (1) A not-so-experienced PHP developer(me) to redesign the current AJAX based chat to the web-socket-chat and get it up and running. (I want to upload the website already :D) (2) Be more compatible on the available web hosts (As deceze mentioned, it might be hard to get them working, for example if I use GoDaddy, Amazon AWS or DigitalOcean)